# Dynamic array based stack

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, stack, push

I'm trying to create a dynamic array based stack and I am getting an index out of bound error when I try to push elements elements onto a full array. I also made the array generic to accommodate all types of stacks.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Stack<T> {
    private int topStack;
    private int stackSize;
    private T[] stack;

    // Constructor
    public Stack(T[] arr) {
        stack = arr;
        stackSize = arr.length;
        topStack = -1;
    }

    // isEmpty
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (topStack == -1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // isFull method
    public boolean isFull() {
        if ((topStack + 1) == stackSize)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // increment array by 10 spaces <-----------------------------------
    public void incrementArray() {
        T[] temp = (T[]) new Object[stackSize*2];
        System.arraycopy(stack, 0, temp, 0, stack.length);
        stack=temp;
        stackSize=stackSize*2;
    }

    // decrement array
    public void decrementArray() {
        stackSize=stackSize/2;
        T[] temp = (T[]) new Object[stackSize];
        System.arraycopy(stack, 0, temp, 0, stackSize);
        stack=temp;
    }

    // push method which adds element to top of stack
    public void push(T element) {
        if (isFull())
            incrementArray();
        topStack=topStack+1;
        stack[topStack] = element;
    }

    // peek method which shows top of stack without popping it
    public T peek() {
        return stack[topStack];
    }

    // pop which copies top of stack, deletes top and returns copy
    public T pop() throws EmptyStackException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        int temp = topStack+1;
        if(temp<stackSize/2)
            decrementArray();
        return stack[topStack--];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Stack operands = new Stack<>(new Integer[0]);
        
            operands.push(2);
            operands.push(1);

    }
}
```

I'm trying to increase the stack size instead of having it overflow out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

You should give your stack an initial `size > 0`. As it stands, your initial `stackSize` is 0. And guess what `stackSize*2` is equal to? And another observation is that you created a generic stack but did not specify a type when creating it in `main`

Also, note that you can change

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (topStack == -1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

to

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return topStack == -1;
}
```

You can make similar changes in other methods that return a `boolean`.

When your code does not behave the way it should, think about what is going on and why that might happen.  Placing ubiquitous print statements thru out your code is a good first step to check on key values to see if they are what you expect them to be.  A more sophisticated method is to use a debugging tool to step thru your program as it executes to look at the values of various fields.

Answer (score 0):

you should use linked list stack which is dynamically allocated memory. those stack never overflow. it is overflow when your computer memory will full

```
public class DynamicStack {

 static  class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int d){
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}

static class Stack{
    public static  Node topHead;

    public static boolean isEmpty(){
        return topHead == null;
    }

    public static void push(int data){
        
        Node newnode = new Node(data);

        if(isEmpty()){
            topHead = newnode;
            return;
        }
        
        newnode.next = topHead;
        topHead = newnode;

    }

    public static int pop(){
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return -1;
        }
        int data = topHead.data;

        topHead = topHead.next;
        return data;
    }

    
    public static int peek(){
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return -1;
        }
        
        return topHead.data;
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack st = new Stack();
    st.push(1);
    st.push(2);
    st.push(3);
    st.push(4);

    while (!st.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(st.peek());
        st.pop();
    }
  }
}
```

i hope this is useful for you